# How to test ViewModel() class which has a function with livedata return?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

good morning.
I am facing some issues to implement a unit test for a splashViewModel class which has a function with livedata.

Here are my class

```
class SplashViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _isOnline = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isOnlineLiveData: LiveData<Boolean> = _isOnline

private val _isPermissionsAccepted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isPermissionsAccepted : LiveData<Boolean> = _isPermissionsAccepted

fun isPermissionsConceded(context: Activity, permissionCode: Int){
   ....
    }
}

fun isConnectivityAvailable(context: Context){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        if(NetworkUtils.isAnyNetworkConnectionAvailable(context)){
            _isOnline.postValue(true)
        } else{
            _isOnline.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is someone can help me to implement a unit test for this class??
i am using kotlin

thanks.

Here are my doubts with unit test

[image: doubt]

Comment: Can you explain a bit on what your test is supposed to do and what blocker you are facing?

Comment: In my viewModel class, i have a function "isConnectivityAvailable( )" which are returning a data into livedata.... 

i want to know how to implement a unit test for this class...